# Javascript calling a subfunction and get return from inside a function

Tags: javascript, function

In a very long function I need to get an user option before continuing the script.

The idea is to get the choosen value ('a' or 'b') with something like this :

```
function myMainFct {

  // a lot of lines here

    if(a_Defined_Value_Is_Ok) { var option="a"; }

    else {
      var choose = "<a onclick=\"myOption('a')\">A</a><a onclick=\"myOption('b')\">B</a>";
      // here I put the <a> choices in a div

        // now the subfunction
        function myOption(x) { return x; }

        // what will happen when I'll get the value
        if (x)  { var option=x; }
    }

    if (option=="a") {
      // let's continue the script for users with "a" option
    }

    else if (option=="b") {
      // let's continue the script for those with "b" option
    }

    // end of common main function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In keeping with your syntax:

```
var x = (function myOption(x) { return x; })();
```

Comment: var x = (function myOption(x) { alert(x);return x; })();  send the alert "Undefined" before clicking

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put the option-handling code in a separate function.

```
function myMainFct {

  //  a lot of lines here

  if(a_Defined_Value_IsOk) 
    myCompletion("a");

  else {
    var choose = "<a onclick=\"myCompletion('a')\">A</a><a onclick=\"myCompletion('b')\">B</a>";
    // here I put the <a> choices in a div

  }
  // end of common main function
}

function myCompletion(option) {

  if (option=="a") { 
    // let's continue the script for users with "a" option
  }

  else if (option=="b") {
    // let's continue the script for those with "b" option
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but I need to continue the script in the main function because I will have to call some other conditions if(a) or if(b) further in the function

Comment: ... all of which could also happen in the continuation function. You could also define the completion function as a function variable (`var myCompletion = function(option) { ... }`) within the main function, in which case it would have access to all of the main function's variables. Otherwise, you're hoping to continue the function after an asynchronous event (the click), and that's just not going to happen.

Comment: OK let's try it :) Thx

Comment: well it's not so easy because I pass a JS array in mainFct(my_array) {

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found another solution. It's not the very best one but it works.

```
function myOption(x) { myMainFct(x); } // return to main function when called

function myMainFct(x) {

  // a lot of lines here

  if(a_Defined_Value_Is_Ok) { var option="a"; }

  else {
    var choose = "<a onclick=\"myOption('a')\">A</a><a onclick=\"myOption('b')\">B</a>";
    // here I put the <a> choices in a div

    if (x)  { var option=x; }
  }

  if (option=="a") {
    // let's continue the script for users with "a" option
  }

  else if (option=="b") {
    // let's continue the script for those with "b" option
  }

  // end of common main function
}
```